# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 "provider not registered" after Access installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 on Windows 64-bit Windows Server(2007). It is okay when I imported data from Excel file in SQL Server Management Studio with Tasks.

Then I installed Access from 64-bit offices 2010 for OLE DB driver `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.
After that, I can import excel file with Tasks any more. The error message is:

```
The provider is not registered on the local machine(system.data)
```

but `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` is fine and can be used in code for `OpenQuery`.

Confused. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Almost identical questions have been asked [many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0+provider+not+registered) on this site, did you find any that apply to your situation?

Comment: Thank you. Resolved it. Each case has a little difference situation.